# Mysql service is missing

Tags: mysql, service

I have installed Mysql server locally and everything was working Ok but today when I tried to get a connection to the local db, I got an error. After checking services showed that the MySql service is missing.

What is the problem?

Comment: Maybe just mysql service is not running ? Have you started it ?

Comment: this service was auto started each time i log into windows

but now the service is absent from services list

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I have done it by the following way

### **You must run in Administrator**

1. Start cmd
2. Go to the "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin"
3. type mysqld --install

Like the following image. [See](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-start-service.html) for more information.

[image]

Comment: Install/Remove of the service Denied!

Comment: The post is quite old, but you just had to open it as an Administrator.

Comment: Open cmd with Administrator rights to avoid "Install/Remove of the service Denied!" error

Comment: Kind of bull crap that they don't mention this in the README file

Answer (score 4):

Go to your mysql bin directory and install mysql service again:

```
c:
cd \mysql\bin
mysqld-nt.exe --install
```

or if mysqld-nt.exe is missing (depending on version):

```
mysqld.exe --install
```

Then go to services, start the service and set it to automatic start.

Comment: i've found the problem.
the service has disappeared after i've installed new CCleaner ver see here :

Comment: Just wanted to point out that on Windows you might have to disable UAC or run CMD as an administrator for this to work (I had to do the latter for it to work) other wise you get a message that states "Install/Remove of the service is denied" - more info here http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,497008,498205#msg-498205

Comment: `cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Cluster 8.0\bin"`   ---- then ---- `mysqld.exe --install`

Answer (score 4):

I also face the same problem. do the simple steps

1. Go to bin directory copy the path and set it as a environment variable.
2. Run the command prompt as admin and cd to bin directory:
3. Run command : mysqld –install
4. Now the services are successfully installed
5. Start the service in service windows of os
6. Type mysql and go

Comment: Open cmd with Administrator rights to avoid "Install/Remove of the service Denied!" error –

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same problem. I properly installed the MYSQL Workbench 6.x, but faced the connection as below:

[image]

I did a bit R&D on this and found that MySQL service in service.msc is not present. To achieve this I created a new connection in MySQL Workbench then manually configured the MySQL Database Server in "**System Profile**" (see the below picture).

You also need to install MySQL Database Server and set a configuration file path for `my.ini`. Now at last test the connection (make sure MySQL service is running in services.msc).

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! Installing MySQL Database Server 8.2 worked. I still don't get it as an installation of Workbench 8.0.34 on another machine including the server but not so on the 2nd.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to have your config file on a different path you *have* to give your service a name:

```
mysqld --install NAME --defaults-file=C:\my-opts2.cnf
```

You can also use the name to install *multiple* mysql services listening on different sockets if you need that for some reason.
You can see why it's failing by copying the execution path and adding --console to the end in the terminal.
Finally, you can modify the starting path of a service by regediting:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\NAME
```

That works well but it isn't as useful because the windows service mechanism provides little logging capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.2\bin

then Open MySQLInstanceConfig file

then complete the wizard.

Click finish

Solve the problem

I think this is the best way to change the port number also.

It works for me