# i can not open mysqld.exe in windows 10 64bit

Tags: mysql

[I did not understand the problem so I could not solve it. I am new in mysql. From the command promt mysql.exe did not open as well as mysqld.exe did not open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4j6n.png)

Comment: MySQL runs as a service in Windows. Have you checked services to see if it's running?

Comment: There is not any service named as SQL/MySQL.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please replace your link with the quoted text and refer to the guidelines an asking questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Check if the MySQL Service Runs. Sometimes it cant run with the local system account.

[MySQL Service is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679258/mysql-service-is-missing)

Comment: the service stopped automatically due to unavailability of another program. windows  does not allow it to running without help of another program such as MySQL community and others